# TabItem LostFocus Event is not firing the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem, lostfocus

I have a `TabControl` with two `TabItem`s. I have a `Thread` running in the first tab. When the first tab loses focus, I have to suspend the thread. But I have a small problem with the `LostFocus` event of the `TabItem`. The `LostFocus` event is not triggered the first time the `TabItem` loses focus, but the second time. Why is this and how do I make it fire the first time?

The following is my xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tbc">
        <TabItem Name="tabMain" Header="Main" GotFocus="tabMain_GotFocus" LostFocus="tabMain_LostFocus" >
            <uc:ucMain />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabExplorer" Header="Data Explorer">
            <uc:ucExplorer />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

In the above code, uc:ucMain is a `UserControl`

Comment: Post sample XAML code here to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a weird WPF behavior. You can work around it by force focusing your first `TabItem`:

Code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tabMain.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I already tried adding this to the constructor of the window: `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(tabMain.Parent, tabMain);`. I also tried what you suggested. It's not working.

Comment: I got it in Window_Loaded event. But the same is not happening in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

TabItem doesn't have focus when you open it first time.

So, set focus on child element of TabItem which in your case is **`ucMain`** . Set [**FocusManager.FocusedElement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on tabItem in XAML itself.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tbc">
        <TabItem Name="tabMain" Header="Main"
                 GotFocus="tabMain_GotFocus"
                 LostFocus="tabMain_LostFocus"
                 FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ucMain}" >
            <uc:ucMain x:Name="ucMain"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabExplorer" Header="Data Explorer">
            <uc:ucExplorer />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **Loaded** event for first **TabItem** Control Name="tabMain".

In that event add below mentioned line.

**tabMain.Focus();**

As **TabControl** does not give focus to first Tab Item when loaded first time, As first tab does not get focused due to that **LostFocus** event does not get triggered because in order to trigger **LostFocus** event **GotFocus** event for once it should be triggered.

Hence allowing **Explicit focus** to First Tab Item.